# Smooks(latest version) configuration in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen Release Milestone 2 (4.7.0 M2)

Tags: smooks

I am trying to configure the Smooks(latest version) in eclipse{Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen Release Milestone 2 (4.7.0 M2)}, But I am getting lot of errors.

Can anyone please help me to configure the Smooks in eclipse with step by step explanation?

I tried to configure the Smooks with external Jar files(downloaded from the https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.smooks), But I got the error.

I need a solution on how to configure the Smooks in Eclipse in correct way.